# How do I deploy an updates project and publish on github?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment, branch

The issues I am having the past few days is that I can not update my 
[https://filipzafran.github.io/Best-TO-DO-App-in-the-history-of-the-universe/](https://filipzafran.github.io/Best-TO-DO-App-in-the-history-of-the-universe/%C2%A0)  website page.

Although the gh-pages branch is updated with the new code, it still shows the old one.

I have:
 - deleted and created again the gh-pages
 - pushed a new commit 
 - re-merged with master
 - cleared browser history (catche)
 - read numerous solutions

Still cant make it publish the new code on my gh-pages website.
I feel like there might have to do with depolyment.

Do I need to deploy again?
Because when I do, from master, it gives me a long error:

```
redux-todo-step_by_step git:(master) npm deploy

Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /home/ficho/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.7 /home/ficho/.nvm/versions/node/v13.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm

Did you mean this?
    repo
```

[This is my repo](https://github.com/FilipZafran/Best-TO-DO-App-in-the-history-of-the-universe).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `deploy` script in your `package.json`, to successfully execute it you have to type in `npm run deploy` as `deploy` isn't an npm command per se.
In npm, `run` is the command that allows you to execute your custom scripts.

Here's an example of a package.json and relative commands...

```json
{
  "name": "raci-api",
  "version": "0.4.0",
  "description": "raci API",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon src/server.js -e \"NODE_END=development\"",
    "start:production": "node src/server.js -e \"NODE_ENV=production\"",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix src/**/*.js",
    "docs:serve": "npx http-server -c-1 docs -o",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "yourRepoURL"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "yourDependencies": "here"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "yourDevDependencies": "here"
  }
}
```

In this case, to properly serve the app (E.G. in loopback) you have to use `npm run start:dev`.

Comment: Hey, I really do appreciate the comment, but I dont see anything what you wrote that my code can relate too. I have 
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",

Comment: The code is just an example package.json. My point was to evidentiate that you must run the script with `npm run deploy` and not `npm deploy`